# Binomial expansion with negative power

Tags: sequences-and-series

Using the binomial expansion, find the taylor series of the function $$f(z) = \frac{1}{(1+z)^3}$$ and find its radius of convergence.

---

The solution is

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2z^n$$

How do we find this? I thought the binomial expansion was

$$(1+z)^n = \sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}z^r$$

but here $n=-3$ so how do we progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binomial formula is still valid for exponents $\alpha$ which are not  natural numbers, but the binomial coefficients 
$$\binom\alpha k=\frac{\alpha(\alpha -1)\dots(\alpha -k+1)}{1\cdot 2\dotsm k}$$
are never $0$, hence an infinite series.

Here, with your notations, you get:
$$\binom{-3}n=\frac{-3(-4)\dotsm{-(n+2)}}{1\cdot2\dotsm n}=(-1)^n\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2.$$

**Alternative way:**
Start from $\;\dfrac1{1+z}=\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^nz^n$, and differentiate twice term by term. The radius of convergence does not change.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Binomial Theorem, for $|x|<1$, the coefficient of $x^r$ is $$\frac{(-3)(-4)...(-(r+2))}{r!}=(-1)^r\frac{1.2.3...(r+2)}{1.2.r!}$$
$$=(-1)^r\frac{(r+1)(r+2)}{2!}$$

Hence the result given